# Installing phpdocumentor on Uniserver

Tags: pear, phpdoc

When I use the PEAR web interface provided by Uniserver 8.8.1 to install phpdocumentor, I get the usual "Downloading..." and then the download finished message. Then, nothing happens.

What do I need to do next?

A quick glance at the packages shows that the program has not been installed.

I've tried using a different browser, rebooting the computer, and using the pear.phpdoc.org channel.

Edit:

When I try to install it from the command line, I get the following:

> Warning: require_once(PEAR.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or director y in Config.php on line 21
>
> Warning: require_once(PEAR.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or director y in C:\UniServer\home\us_pear\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on
>   line 21
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PEAR.php'
>   (include_path='C :\Coral_8_7_3\z_test_1\UniServer\home\us_pear\PEAR')
>   in C:\UniServer\home\us_pea r\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 21

Answer (score 0):

Use the ´pear.bat` command line utility instead of the web interface. It will give you better error messages.

---

Your PEAR installation is broken. Re-install it by downloading and executing `go-pear.phar`.